# JavaFx ListView problems in full screen

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fullscreen

I've been having problems with the ListView control being strange when the application is in full screen. It is rare for me to be able to select 2 items in a row without it acting like I didn't click at all. This is all however fine when not in full screen mode. This occurs in several different programs of mine, and is almost a deal breaker for using JavaFx.
I have noticed the same behavior in JRE 1.8.0_40 and 1.8.0._60. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. I'm unsure on whether or not this is a bug, or something I am doing wrong.

Here's some code to replicate the error:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            ListView<String> view = new ListView<>();
            view.setPrefHeight(300);
            view.setPrefWidth(100);
            root.getChildren().add(view);

            view.getItems().addAll("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5");

            primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce on Mac OS X 10.11.1, Java 1.8.0_66.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try and update my JRE and then try.